# pass trace information from stepfunctions to aws lambda (container)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-xray

I have a stepfunction that calls multiple lambda functions. with tracing activated in both services.
I have noticed, when i call the lambda function directly i see trace information, the same thing when i call stepfunction (which calls lambda). problem is, when a lambda is called by a stepfunction, the traces do not show up at all. is there  requirement on explicitely configuring this so that a stepfunction call would also trigger tracing for that lambda
Here is the code for the state machine:

```
{
  "Comment": "My State Machine",
  "StartAt": "MapCalculcationObjectToFile",
  "States": {
    "MapCalculcationObjectToFile": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
          "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
        },
        "StartAt": "File Processing",
        "States": {
          "File Processing": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
            "Parameters": {
              "Payload.$": "$",
              "FunctionName": "arn-for-my-lambda"
            },
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Lambda.ServiceException",
                  "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                  "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                  "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 1,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "ResultPath": "$",
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "Next": "Success",
      "InputPath": "$.items",
      "Label": "MapCalculcationObjectToFiles",

    },
    "Success": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Success Run",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about using X-Ray with Step Functions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-xray-tracing.html).

The State Machine has a configuration option to enable x-ray tracing. You can enable that via the AWS Management Console, [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stepfunctions-statemachine-tracingconfiguration.html), or the Step Functions API for CreateStateMachine or [UpdateStateMachine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_UpdateStateMachine.html).

[image]

When you do this, Step Functions will automatically pass the same trace header to your Lambda function invocations.

Comment: aparently, in aws stepfunction distributed mode, tracing is not activated and does not work